# redirect on rails to edit_user_path(current_user)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am using stripe on my app and after someone puts in their info I want the page to redirect for them to edit their profile, which is `edit_user_path(current_user)`

How would I trigger a redirect after a few seconds to that page?

I was thinking about the javascript below but how would I make the URL the user edit path?

```
<script> 

$(document).ready(function () {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        location.href = "https://www.google.co.in";
    }, 5000);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While rendering your view on the server side, you need to export the `edit_user_path(current_user)` from ruby context to javascript context.

There are several ways to export data from ruby to javascript. One of the approaches is to use `javascript_tag` and you could assign to a javascript variable as follows (just an example):

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  window.edit_current_user_path = '<%= edit_user_path(current_user) %>'
<% end %>
```

Then you could use that variable in your javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        location.href = window.edit_current_user_path;
    }, 5000);
});
</script>
```

Refer to [JavaScriptHelper#javascript_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-javascript_tag) for more info:

Answer (score 0):

You could make a hidden element with a data attribute in rails.  Then read that tag from jquery.

```
<div class='thing' data-thing='<%=edit_user_path(current_user)%>' style='display:none;'></div>


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.thing').attr("data-thing"); //path
});
```